# Get first reaction that the user picks discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm sending a quiz to users and trying to listen for their first reaction. The problem is how can I get the first reaction each one picks and not the others? I can't find a way to figure out which reaction each one picks first since many times users pick many reactions.

Something like:

> **Which is the color Red?**

Each user answers with the reactions the bot provides, and after a little time the bot shows the right answer with the winners and losers.

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor(0x00AE86)
  .setDescription('the quizz');

message.channel.send({
  embed
}).then(async m => {
  let emojis = icons.slice(0, size.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < emojis.length; i++) {
    await m.react(icons[i]);
  }

  const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return emojis.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;
  };

  m.awaitReactions(filter, {
      time: 60000
    })
    .then(collected => {

      const reaction = collected.array();

      for (var i = 0; i < reaction.length; i++) {
        let users = reaction[i].users.cache.array();
        console.log(users);

        for (var k = 1; k < users.length; k++) {
          let wallet = db.get(args[1] + '_' + users[k].id);
          if (parseInt(args[0]) > wallet) {

            message.channel.send('You don't have money.');
            return;
          } else {
            let bet = icons.indexOf(reaction[i].emoji.name);
            let answer = users[k].id + ',' + size[ans];
            db.push('answer_xx', answer);
            m.channel.send('We saved your answer.');
          }
        }
      }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer did not answer the question, after submitting an edit for your question for clarification, I believe I now understand what you want.

The best way to prevent people from reacting and firing your bot multiple times is to remove all reactions from the message you sent:

```
message.reactions.removeAll().catch(error => console.error('Failed to clear reactions: ', error));
```

If this solution is not enough, you would need to store users that have answered somewhere, and use a filter for their user IDs after they react.

```
const filter = (reaction, user, USERS) => {
return emojis.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;
};
```